# How to use redirection with parameters with Devise authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

A user can share a link in their profile and if a person is not logged in it will redirect them to the login page - this is working.

I want to pass in some sort of parameter to the login page.

For example, if the original URL is:

```
https://mywebsite.com/users/product/24?randomid=500
```

and the user is not logged it will redirect them to:

```
https://mywebsite.com/login
```

Can the parameter `randomid` get passed along, such as:

```
https://mywebsite.com/login&?randomid=500
```

I am using Devise for the authentication and this is what the routes file looks like:

```
devise_for :users,
           path: '',
           controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'},
           path_names: {
               sign_in: 'login',
               sign_out: 'logout',
               sign_up: 'signup'
   }
```

I don't specify the redirection manually, it does it automatically.

Comment: I think this was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903589/passing-through-parameters-during-devise-login.  Let me know if that helps you.  If not perhaps add a bit of detail to the questions around what specifically you want to use the param for ect.

Comment: @ruby_newbie Users want to share their products to facebook but a logged in user cannot see until they are logged in. Which raises another problem about the OpenGraph for facebook not being able to see the title of product. My goal is when I share, to pass a param, and then when facebook redirects it uses that param and I do a db look up and fill In the OG tags.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". It's important to show us what you tried, and tell us why it didn't work. We also need just enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: You should be able to infer the answer from the other question I linked.  If not, read the Tin Man's link and reformat the question accordingly.

Comment: @theTinMan The question is how to get something to redirect using Devise to also pass in parameters. Note: I do not manually specify "redirect_to", the system does it automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update